# Network Anomaly detection

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, anomaly-detection, prediction

I am working on a problem to identify anomaly in Network. I am stuck at how to handle the following issues 
1. VPN Land Based Violation (Login from Multiple locations within unrealistic situation
2. VPN Timebased violation- Multiple logins at the same time
I know we can figure this out using a simple sql query.. but How do we deploy the model in production to find these? Like how do we deploy a model to find out if the person has logged in Asia and in the next hour login from Europe. 
Aprreciate any help.

I will collect data from Spark using Kafka stream and then will run a machine learning model to detect Anomalies. I will be building a behaviour profile for each user. I need help with How do i actually set it up so that the data can be collected from spark continuously and exported to cloud or should I use Spark MLlib to run the model and then export the results(or threats) to a database which can be viewed by Security? or Just use Spark MLlib and setup such that alerts can be sent to the network team. New to Spark and cloud sorry if I am not clear
Thank you

Comment: It seems like this could be solved without any machine learning or anomaly detection.  Why don't you just set a limit on time and location?

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?  What do you mean by "How do we deploy a model"? If you know how to detect this, what exactly is the challenge with "deploying" it?  Please edit the question to provide more context.